# Escaping dashes does not work for Redis Search TEXT field

Tags: redis

I have Redis hash-maps of the following structure:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL lock:f17bffd8-49b6-11ed-ab71-e884a53f6d8a
1) "locked_at"
2) "1665604465"

3) "locked_until"
4) "1665627585"

5) "comment"
6) "AeRbWxEDWDKDmKh"
 
7) "id"
8) "f17bffd8-49b6-11ed-ab71-e884a53f6d8a"
 
9) "locked"
10) "0"
 
11) "resource"
12) "wikichems"

13) "type"
14) "single"

15) "group"
16) "f17bffd9-49b6-11ed-ab71-e884a53f6d8a"
```

and I created an index for them in Redis Search which looks like this:

```
FT.CREATE idx:lock 
ON hash 
PREFIX 1 "lock:" 
SCHEMA 
    locked NUMERIC SORTABLE 
    resource TAG SORTABLE
    type TAG SORTABLE
    group TEXT SORTABLE
    locked_at NUMERIC SORTABLE 
    locked_until NUMERIC SORTABLE
```

I want to be able to search by the `group` field which is type of `TEXT` and represents `UUID` converted to the string. According to the documentation:

> Escaping separators in both queries and documents is done by
> prepending a backslash to any separator. e.g. the text `hello\-world hello-world` will be tokenized as `[hello-world, hello, world]`. NOTE
> that in most languages you will need an extra backslash when
> formatting the document or query, to signify an actual backslash, so
> the actual text in redis-cli for example, will be entered as
> `hello\\-world`.

So I am trying to do this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx:lock "@group:f17bffd8\-49b6\-11ed\-ab71\-e884a53f6d8a"
1) (integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx:lock "@group:f17bffd8\\-49b6\\-11ed\\-ab71\\-e884a53f6d8a"
1) (integer) 0
```

but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Redis specs

```
redis_version:6.2.7
module:name=search,ver=20415,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[ReJSON],options=[handle-io-errors]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `group` as a TEXT field which enables full-text search. This type is optimized for human-readable text and so punctuation is stripped out of the index. A hyphen counts as punctuation. This makes sense if you think about hyphenated words. For example for word `heat-seeking` you would want to to match `heat` and `seek`.

It looks like you are using the UUID as a foreign key of some sort. A better option would be to mark this as a TAG field. This type is optimized for IDs and faceted searches. Then it will match the string that you are providing. Note that TAG fields are case-insensitive.

To query a TAG, put the value in curly braces when you query it.

`FT.SEARCH idx:lock @group:{f17bffd8-49b6-11ed-ab71-e884a53f6d8a}`

I'm not sure if you'll need to escape the hyphens or not. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: Using TAG instead of TEXT seems reasonable. In this case you should escape hyphens with two backslashes: `FT.SEARCH idx:lock "@group:{f1718171\\-49b6\\-11ed\\-ab58\\-e884a53f6d8a}"`. I will leave the question unanswered, maybe someone will suggest something about proper way to escape hyphens in TEXT-fields and will help someone who will encounter such problem in the future. Thank you!